Why is My Python Script Hanging When Making HTTP Requests with requests Library?
I’m using Python's requests library to make HTTP GET requests in a script, but the program occasionally hangs indefinitely without throwing an error. Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import requests  

url = "https://example.com/api/data"  

try:  
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)  
    if response.status_code == 200:  
        print(response.json())  
    else:  
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")  
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  
    print(f"Request failed: {e}")  

Issues:
The script works most of the time but hangs on some requests without triggering the timeout.
Setting a timeout in the requests.get() call doesn’t always seem to prevent the hanging issue.
The same issue persists on different networks, so I don’t think it’s a local connectivity problem.
What I’ve Tried:
Tested the URL in a browser and with curl, and it seems to work fine.
Tried using session instead of requests.get(), but the issue still occurs.
Enabled logging with http.client to debug, but didn’t find anything conclusive.
Is there a better way to handle these intermittent hanging issues with requests? Should I consider an alternative library or specific configuration for better reliability?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What error code do you get when it is in the hanging state? Loading time could vary due to different reasons.
